# Proper way to take care of boxing gloves and wrist wraps after use?

Tags: equipment

After heavy usage, boxing gloves and wrist wraps can get build up mildew and other nasties. What should I do the keep my gloves and wraps in good shape?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with boxing gloves is that they get moist inside, and don't always get a chance to dry. What you can do is to crumple a few pages from your local newspaper and stuff that into it. That will absorb the sweat, and they won't get moldy.

I've also heard of people putting them in the freezer or out in the sun, but I'm not sure if any of these are good options. It seems most logical to me to make sure they dry up properly.

As for wrist wraps, simply unroll them and hang them over something, and toss them in the washing machine once in a while. Fortunately, wrist wraps are inexpensive, and can easily be replaced when they're done for.

Comment: I think freezer would just delay the growth of mildew. Sun drying though seems to be fairly reliable for a number of things, so I'd say that might actually work. I'm still concerned though that the sun doesn't get directly inside the gloves.

Comment: Do you mean "crumple" (as in scrunch up), rather than "crumble" (turn into crumbs)?

Answer (score 5):

I wash my handwraps every other class.  They don't take up much space in the wash machine so it's no trouble at all.  I would recommend getting one of those lingerie/delicates  laundry bags to put them in, or they turn into a tangled disaster.

as for the gloves like everyone else says, dry them out/ sanitize them after class. and don't store them in a bag.  i  hang mine on the outside of my gear bag,  keeps them and my bag from getting smelly.

my coach has these freshner things that are a mesh bag full of volcano pebbles.   they supposedly absorb the moisture from the gloves.  and then every few months you put them out in the sun for a day and they are good to go again.

one last trick is to put a dryer sheet in each glove.  they smell fantastic!

Comment: keeping the hand wraps very clean will help keep the boxing gloves fresh as well.

Answer (score 4):

For my large MMA/Boxing gloves:

1. Spray Lysol on the inside
2. Wipe it down with a dry paper towel
3. With a damp paper towel wipe down the inside
4. With all straps/Velcro open let try and air out in a well ventilated area

I normal wrap my hands in the paper towels to clean out the inside of the glove. For wrist straps I always let them hang dry in a well ventilated area. Using the Lysol has kept my new gloves from developing the smell that my old ones eventually got, even though I let them ventilate and dry every time.

Answer (score 1):

I try to wash my hand-wraps between uses, and if I can't, I at least hang-dry them. They get smelly and gross fast.

My gloves, I try to take out of my bag between uses. I also have some cardboard tubes with holes punched in the sides that I jam in there to get some air flow and dryness action on the inside.

I have not tried these methods for more than a couple months at a time; so I don't know if they'll work for heavy usage over the long term.

Answer (score 1):

I'll list a couple of methods which i have tested and works for me.

Gloves
1. Wrap you gloves in a plastic bag and freeze them. By freezing it you kill most of the bacteria / fungus in it. I use this method when i am away from home.

1. Put baking soda after use to kill fungus. This will eliminate bad odor from cropping out.
2. Ur a dryer to gently dry gloves using an indoor dryer or hair dryer. I've sun dried my gloves before and the outer layer started to peel soon after.

Wraps.

1. I usually toss the wraps in the washing machine and fan dry them.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

Put some an open container of baking soda in your gloves. Don't spill it everywhere. The baking soda will absorb the funky smell of work.

Answer (score -1):

Get a hand wrap wash bag + this one comes with an extra set of wraps >> https://savagebreedcombat.com/collections/accessories/products/hand-wrap-wash-bag-wraps

It is designed to hold and wash your hand wraps preventing them from tangling. Putting them in the bag will save you time and hassle from having to untangle them.

This bag holds 5 wraps at a time and is breathable if you wanted to put it in the dryer.

Your welcome ;)

Comment: This looks like spam.

Comment: There is a lot that is implicit or unsaid in your answer, which makes it appear to be only promotional (ie spam). If you expand your answer it would look better - for example mention how you could use the bag and then soak in a bucket of Vanish.